# Convert Where IN sub-query to an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can the below query be converted to using an inner join instead of the where IN subquery?

```
select i.*, it.*
from ItemTypes it
    inner join Items i on (i.itemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID)
where i.itemID IN (......)
```

I might have 100 results returned in the sub-query and I want to avoid having that in a sub-query.

Comment: you omitted the subquery, how are we supposed to find out whether it could be rewritten with join?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `IN`? It is a semi join anyway and generally more efficient in SQL Server as rewriting as a join can introduce duplicates.

Comment: where i.itemID IN (12313,123123,25234,1234345234,12342,123422,34,13435) but I might have 100 or more ID's in the IN clause.

Comment: @codecompleting - So what? If they are being returned from a sub query it doesn't matter. Look at the execution plan it will be implemented as a semi join. It is less efficient to rewrite it using `JOIN` explicitly then using `DISTINCT` to get rid of the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [WITH common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with SelectedItems (selectedIDs) as
(
    select distinct itemID from [...] where [...]
)
select i.*, it.*
from ItemTypes it
inner join Items i on i.itemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID
inner join SelectedItems on selectedIDs = i.itemID
```

You could also define a temporary #Table with an index to hold the selections:

```
create table #SelectedItems
(
    selItemID int primary key clustered
)
insert into #SelectedItems (selItemID)
select [...]

select i.*, it.*
from ItemTypes it
inner join Items i on i.itemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID
inner join #SelectedItems si on si.selItemID = i.itemID

drop table #SelectedItems
```

But whatever you do, be careful to measure performance before and after any change.

Comment: Your CTE's `SelectedItems` view would also need a `distinct` keyword, as @MartinSmith pointed out in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.*, it.*
from ItemTypes it
    inner join Items i on (i.itemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID)
    inner join (select itemID from Items where ...) i2 ON i.itemID = i2.itemID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this

```
select i.*, it.*
from ItemTypes it
    inner join Items i on (i.itemTypeID = it.ItemTypeID)
    inner join (select distinct itemID from [...] where [...]) i2
        on (i.itemID = i2.itemID)
```

But I doubt you'll get benefits from this. After all, modern databases tend to find the optimal execution plan for common queries and clauses. In this case, however, extra work might be needed to get rid of duplicates using the `distinct` operator

Comment: It would need `DISTINCT` to maintain the same semantics as `IN`.

Comment: Maybe I should put my ID's in a table type, and then join on that?

Comment: @codecompleting: Have you actually measured this to be slow? Do you have appropriate indexes on all relevant columns?